# Construct a $2\times3$ system $Ax=b$ with particular solution $(2,4,0)$ and a null space = any multiple of $(1,1,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not sure how to go about this. also, why can't I do this with a $1\times3$ matrix? Why must it be a $2\times3$?

Comment: A $1\times 3$ will result in a null space that is a plane, not a line as you require. You need to have only one degree of freedom. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy matrix whose nullspace consists of the multiples of $(1,1,1)$:
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-1\\
0&1&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, in order to set up the question properly, all we need to do is calculate $A$ multiplied by our particular solution.  That is,
$$
\vec b = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-1\\
0&1&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\,
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
4\\
0
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: thanks.   I figured it out.  I was interpreting the problem wrong.  I was trying to create a matrix that satisfied both conditions, not a system.  I just needed some sleep, apparently.  glad to see you got the same solution I did though.  now I feel confident.  thanks again!